# Render pages based on content driven from a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to learn RoR, normally I develop in Node.js so what I mean by rendering pages based on content driven from a database is:

If I have a title, a body, and maybe a date how can I loop through a table, and for each one load content to the page based on that? In Node.js (Jade template language) it would be something like:

```
for item in array
h2= item.title
p=  item.date
p=  item.body
```

Hope I made myself clear, thanks!

(It doesn't have to be an array, it just happened to be in Node, whatever the most efficient way is)

Comment: `array.each do |item|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking to loop through an object and display data? Hope I didn't misunderstand you, but you can access the data like this for example:

```
array = YourActiveRecordObject.all 

array.each do |item|
   item.title
   item.date
   item.body
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in a haml view.

```
- array.each do |item|

  %h2= item.title
  %p= item.date
  %p= item.body
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses a Model-View-Controller organizational structure [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). What you are looking for goes in the View for the particular resource. For example, if you scaffolded a resource called Item, you could go to app/views/items/index.html.erb and find this:

```
<% @items.each do |i| %>
  <h2><%= i.title %></h2>
  <p><%= i.date %></p>
  <p><%= i.body %></p>
<% end %>
```

By default, Rails uses the ERB templating engine, but there are others available.

Answer (score 0):

In controller you would define a variable `@items` for the array returned by the query to your model as:

```
@items = itemModel.all
#or whatever the query you need for those items are
```

And then in the view you would loop through them. With haml it would be:

```
- @items.each do |item|
  %h2
    = item.title
  %p
    = item.date
  %p
    = item.body
```